# How to add a specific database from mysqldump

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I need to copy specific record from 1 database. The problem is that i can't find the way to insert only one database from mysqldump file.

1. File is too big to even try open it in txt editor.
2. File is too big to upload it in phpmyadmin

   I aslo could't find how to do it in mysql console (only how to add 1 database from database.sql file, but in current case i am using mysqldump, so that won't work).

I am using wamp on localhost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

`mysql -u username -p -D reqd_database --one-database < database.sql`

This will source only the SQL queries that apply to the chosen database.

Comment: In comand prompt it returns me "mysql is not recognized as an internal command, operable program or batch file". And if i try that in mysql console, returns ->(arrows that command is not finished)

Comment: This command has to be run from the command prompt and not in Mysql shell/console. It says not recognized because the path of mysql executable is not known. And, before running this query create the reqd_database if not available.

Comment: So i will have to declare path for mysql in system variables? or run this command in mysql home folder? thank you for your help